# How do i remove box surrounding the image while using hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

A rectange is appearing outside the link which i dont want. How do u remove it.
[No Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/45433120@N04/4171187269/)

```
<a href="~/Web Pages/Home.aspx" runat="server">
    <img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/TestToday.png") %>" alt="No image" width="200" height="200"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
border = "0"
```

that will do the trick

or in css:

```
img {
    border:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this CSS rule:

```
a img {border: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css:

```
:link img { border: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably see the anchor tags border.

Try adding `BORDER="0"` to your `a` tag. Or set border to none in your stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the dotted outline that appears when clicking a link?

Try

```
a:active
{
 outline: none;
}
```

this removes the outline when clicking, but not when entering the link using the keyboard (which is when it's really needed).

Answer (score 0):

try this use `ForeColor="White"`

```
<asp:hyperlink runat="server" ImageUrl ="Images/back.jpg" D="hlBack" ForeColor="White" >
</asp:hyperlink>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this answer works great with IE 10, but not IE 10 Compat View, or at least that's what I'm seeing in my testing. I'm still giving it an upvote though, because I tried all of the other tricks of setting the border to none, but not a single one of them worked in either IE 10 or IE 10 Compat View.

Comment: No good if your background is not white. Doesn't remove the border, just sets it the same colour as the background.